# How to output curly brackets in a TYPO3 Fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid

By using this in a TYPO3 Fluid template

```
<f:uri.action arguments="{start: '\{start\}'}" [...] />
```

I would expect the following output

```
index.php?id=1&tx_plugin_pi1[start]={start}...         // unescaped
index.php?id=1&tx_plugin_pi1%5Bstart%5D=%7Bstart%7D... // escaped
```

But I get this

```
index.php?id=1&tx_plugin_pi1[start]=\{start\}...             // unescaped
index.php?id=1&tx_plugin_pi1%5Bstart%5D=%5C%7Bstart%5C%7D... // escaped
```

How can I get the expected result?

**UPDATE:** There is a feature request for this on forge: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46257. But I still don't know how to get this fixed on a array like arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution inspired by http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46257#note-7 but without using a controller

```
<f:alias map="{ocb: '{', ccb: '}'}">
    <f:uri.action arguments="{start: '{ocb}start{ccb}'}" [...] />
</f:alias>
```